# How can I make a sales report in firebase per month?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I can already get the sales of the orders with this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    var totalIncome = 0;
    firestore
      .collection("orders")
      .get()
      .then(function (querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
          totalIncome += doc.data().total;
        });
        console.log(totalIncome); //sales report
      });
  });
```

Now, how can I make a sales per month?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like this.

```
useEffect(() => {
 return firestore
 .collection("orders")
 .orderBy("orderCreatedAt", "asc")
 .get()
 .then((orders) => ordersHistoryMonthly(orders.docs));
},[])

function ordersHistoryMonthly(orders = []) {
 let totalPerMonth = [];
 let startDate = getMinDate(orders);
 let endDate = getMaxDate(orders);
 let labels = getDates(startDate, endDate, "MMMM YYYY", "month");
 labels.forEach((m) => {
   let totalIncome = 0;
   orders.forEach((o, i) => {
     let oDate = moment(new Date(o.orderCreatedAt.seconds * 1000),"DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm");
     if (oDate.format("MMMM YYYY") === m) 
       totalIncome += Number(o.total);
   });
   totalPerMonth.push(totalIncome);
 });
}

function getDates(startDate, stopDate, format = "DD-MM-YYYY", unit = "days") {
 let dateArray = [];
 let currentDate = moment(startDate);
 const stop = moment(stopDate);
 while (currentDate <= stop) {
   dateArray.push(moment(currentDate).format(format));
   currentDate = moment(currentDate).add(1, unit);
 }
 return dateArray;
}

function getMinDate(orders) {
 let date = moment(new Date());
 if (orders) {
   if (orders[0]) {
     date = moment(new Date(orders[0].orderCreatedAt.seconds * 1000));
   }
 }
 return date;
}

function getMaxDate(orders) {
 let date = moment(new Date());
 if (orders) {
   if (orders[orders.length - 1]) {
     date = moment(
       new Date(orders[orders.length - 1].orderCreatedAt.seconds * 1000)
     );
   }
 }
 return date;
}
```

:D

Answer (score 1):

To get the sum of all `total` fields, you have to:

1. Read all the documents into your application code, and
2. Add up the individual values.

There is not shortcut for this, as Firestore doesn't support so-called aggregation queries.

Since the above process is slow and expensive, it is often better to actually store a running total for all aggregate values your app needs. For more on this, I recommend reading the Firebase documentation on [aggregation queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/aggregation), and [distributed counters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters).

Based on that, you should be able to get something working. If you run into trouble while implementing this, I recommend posting back with the [minimal code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you, was only looking for documentations for now and will try to work it out

Comment: I could now retrieve the sum of the field 'total' for the sales report. How ca I generate a sales report per month?

Comment: You have the same choice to make there as for the other aggregation queries: you either read all relevant documents, or you have to store the aggregated value in the database itself and update it upon every (relevant) write operation.